# Debian: Network connection dropping randomly

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wifi

I am having an issue with my network connection dropping after a while, sometimes an hour if I'm lucky two. I can regain the connection by running:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup --force wlan0
```

when I run `ifconfig wlan0` it shows its still connected with the same ip address but the packet loss keeps growing. Can someone point me in the right direction on where to start to diagnose this issue? I am unsure of what logs to look at besides `/var/log/syslogs and /var/log/messages`.

Comment: What wireless NIC do you have? It's often the case that with wireless-N NICs that they don't work that well under Linux. There are several Q&As on this site to this effect.

Comment: Take note of these Q&A's regarding this type of issue w/ wireless-N: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7453+%22wireless-n%22